# Is it recommended to store files on NTFS partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs

I am using Win10 + Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot and I have a sharing folder which is a NTFS partition, right now I don't see any issues, also from both sides I sync the files by the same cloud app and I don't see any issues. But I am just wondering is it general very safe to do so? Right I only share files that are not so important also they are synced on cloud, but say in case i have something very important, is it recommended to store such file on the ntfs partition?

Comment: Personally my problem would be that I often use in my filenames characters that are not allowed in NTFS/Windows, such as colons, hash tags, question marks, etc. These files and all the files stores within a such named folder are not accessible under Windows then. Personally I use exFat and ext4 for most things.

Comment: The main problem is that NTFS uses no file permissions, at least none that Ubuntu can handle. Your system files would not function properly if stored on NTFS. However your personal data, like documents and media that are going to be accessed by you only, can be safely stored there.

Comment: The two most critical problems will be file name conventions (Windows is case insensitive, while Linux is case sensitive: a and A are two different files in Linux, while in Windows you won't be able to access one of them. Special characters like : ? * " ' will make a Linux file inaccessible to Windows. Etc.) and user/group ownership plus file access permissions.

Comment: You should use windows_names parameter in fstab. example: `defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names` more info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983336 Always make sure Windows fast start up is off: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  There will soon be released a case insensitive option in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, so basically if you don't run important linux files and as long as you store important but not linux specific files you're fine. I have already created permission for ntfs as @oldfred mentioned as everything is fine. Except that in order to make it work properly I need to fully shutdown windows every time by inputting `shutdown /s /f ` in cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes an NTFS partition is the only way of sharing files between Windows and Linux. For example bash scripts that I run in Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 and Windows 10 WSL are stored in in an NTFS partition mounted in Ubuntu as `/mnt/e/bin/`. On the Windows side the NTFS partition it is accessed as drive `E:\`

I have run into anomalies where I have to create the bash script on the Ubuntu site first to get proper editing permissions from the Windows 10 WSL side. This could be my system setup fault though and I honestly haven't cared enough to research it that deeply.

Ubuntu running under Windows 10 WSL does recognize and can change Linux file permissions properly but cannot access `ext4` partitions, only `NTFS` partitions.

There is a Windows add-on to read/write `ext4` partitions but there are/were data corruption problems in 64-bit mode. As such I stopped using this Windows 10 add-on.

Ubuntu seems to have no problems updating Windows NTFS partitions for changing the Linux file permissions. As far as changing Windows file permissions it is rather complicated and I'll leave that up to you to research.